# Blend for VS 2022 - PathListBox problems

Tags: wpf-controls, expression-blend, blend

I am struggling to get the PathListBox control working in Blend for VS 2022. I have tried to follow a number of tutorials and try as I might I cannot get it to work. I am beginning to wonder if it does actually works at all.

I have created a simple UserControl and tried it and also just a simple Page and tried it but to no avail.
The code below is the complete page. What I am expecting is the Labels to be evenly spaced around the ellipse.
Longer term what I am trying to do is create a Dial Gauge using the Arc control with pipe signs as increments around the dial.

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DialGauge2"
             xmlns:ec="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/controls"
    xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" 
             xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:Collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib" x:Class="DialGauge2.UserControl1" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#FFD51E1E" Height="137" Width="136" >
            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Fill="#FFF2EBEB"/>

            <ec:PathListBox Foreground="#FFF1EBEB" Margin="0,0,70,58">
                <ec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
                    <ec:LayoutPath SourceElement="{Binding ElementName=ellipse}" Distribution="Even" Orientation="OrientToPath" />
                </ec:PathListBox.LayoutPaths>
                <Label Content="Label"/>
                <Label Content="Label"/>
                <Label Content="Label"/>


            </ec:PathListBox>

        </Grid>

    </Viewbox>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: Hmm.. If I remove the <Viewbox> then it seems to work. I wonder why that is

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found the problem.
Removing the  made the labels appear. But why?
So I added the Viewbox back and used the Blend Controls menu to do that and it all worked. What was the difference?
What I had done is this.
In following the tutorial I had manually added   around the Grid by typing it into the XAML. The code looked all OK but "Objects and Timeline" pane didn't show the Viewbox control and I hadn't noticed this.
Adding it via the Controls menu I now have the Viewbox control sitting immediately above the Grid.
Cheers
Andy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).